# How the second in var will be 2, since we are accessing it outside its scope

Tags: java

Please explain how the second in var will be 2 since, we are accessing outside it scope. o/p - in=1 out=2 in=2

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int var = 1;
        System.out.println("in="+var);
        {
            var = 2;
            System.out.println("out="+var);
        }
        System.out.println("in="+var);
    }
}
```

Comment: The scope of `var` is the `main()` method because that is where you define it. Hence your output will be `1, 2, 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `var` is controlled by the outer declaration. You only have a single `var`. You can't *shadow* `var` as posted because it is a local variable. **However**, if we tweak it a little bit for the example.

```
static int var = 1;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("in="+var);
    {
        int var = 2;
        System.out.println("out="+var);
    }
    System.out.println("in="+var);
}
```

**Does** shadow the externally declared `var`. And it does output

```
in=1
out=2
in=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare a variable and initialize it with value   `int var = 1;`

Now you change it's value `var = 2;` , so value of var is 2.

`System.out.println("in="+var);` will print latest value of var which is 2.